# Focusing on textBox after clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Okay. So for my college class I have to make a simple calculator in C# using Windows Forms (doing more demanding version with `.Split()`). Got a `textBox` and few `buttons`. So f.e. I insert number 3 into a `textBox` but then I want to press a `button` which would add a `+` symbol after my number. And yes, it does it. But then, if I want to go back to writing stuff to my `textBox` I have to click on in once again.

And now I found answers like use `.Focus()` or use `.Select()`, and they work, but not as I would want them to do, because they additionally mark the whole `textBox.text` like you would select it with your mouse, in blue color, and if I press another number then I would erase everything from `textBox`. Is there a way to do this without marking the whole text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of just using `.Focus()` go for this combination:

```
// Set focus to control
txtbox.Focus();
// Set text-selection to end
txtbox.SelectionStart = txtbox.Text.Length == 0 ? 0 : txtbox.Text.Length -1;
// Set text-selection length (in your case 0 = no blue text)
txtbox.SelectionLength = 0
```

OR

```
// Set focus to control
txtbox.Focus();

// Check if text is longer then 0
if(txtbox.Text.Length > 0)
{
    // Set text-selection to end
    txtbox.SelectionStart = txtbox.Text.Length -1;
    // Set text-selection length (in your case 0 = no blue text)
    txtbox.SelectionLength = 0
}
```

Both ways are the same. In the first one, I check for `text-length == 0` in-place in the second line.

In the second one, I use a classical `if` statement.